# Connecting to remote Databases in Ruby DBI

Tags: ruby

How Can I Connect to remote databases in ruby ?

I have an application that I need to connect to my remote host databases and read those databases  table and map into my application .

Thank YOu for the help in advance

Comment: I have tried like this. For example like this . require 'rubygems' require 'mysql2' db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => 'root', :password=> 'password', :database => 'toolkitmar16' )    I can connect to local database but not remote host.

Comment: add this to your question, show us what error you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is incomplete. You didn't mention which database. I'm assuming mysql. You should also show your efforts.

Install mysql gem from http://tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

```
gem install mysql
```

Now, use this in your ruby file.

```
db = Mysql.new(hostname, username, password, database)
```

example:

```
require 'mysql'
db = Mysql.new('209.88.228.142', 'someuser', 'exceptionalpassword', 'greatdb')
```

Put your server's IP or host in the **hostname**. Rest of the parameters are self-explanatory.  You must allow your public IP address in the remote servers mysql host. For example, if your IP is like 209.88.228.142, you must allow this IP in your mysql server.

See the [doc](http://tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/) for more detail.

**Allowing your IP in the database server.** 
Assuming the above mentioned IP is your public IP, you can allow access to your *greatdb* database using the following command. Run it in your db server's console.

```
GRANT ALL ON greatdb.* TO someuser@'209.88.228.142' IDENTIFIED BY 'exceptionalpassword';
```

Note: Replace username, dbname, password, host/ip with appropriate values for you.

Comment: I can connect to local database  like this , but I cannot to remote database for example I need to connect to my Amazon Hosted application database.

Comment: I need the Connection String syntax to connect to a remote database

Comment: You need to allow your client's IP in mysql server. see this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails: Yes it is possible. For most other drivers its possible to, please let us know what you have tried.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: name_of_databse
  pool: 20
  username: user
  password: password
  wait_timeout: 3600
  host: name.of.server
  port: 3306
```

Comment: I mean not through the database configuration. I would like to connect to remote database using core programming in ruby.  For example like this . require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2' db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => 'root', :password=> 'password', :database => 'toolkitmar16'   )

Comment: @RANZIT----user1242400 ah, you should really rework your question. As it is now you are are wasting the time of the people who try to help you (sorry for the harsh words...)

Answer (score -1):

You should also notice that the mysql you probably want to connect to allows remote access. Please check if you can connect remotely with a db-tool (like squirrel) or with the mysql client.

Normally, useres in a mysql database are restricted in the CREATE USER statement to localhost or to specific remote hosts like this:

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

So please ensure that in the remote database is a user with `'monty'@'%'` or `'monty'@'yourhosthere'`

For details, see the [mysql reference "Access Control"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html)